# spatial database query (the closest shop to a specific address)

Tags: sql, database, location, spatial, closest

```
Database name: landmarks

landmark(landmarkId(PK),landmarkName,type,GPSCoordinates,locationId)

Comments(commentId(PK),comment,landmarkId)

Location(locationId(PK),streetName,streetNumber,buildingNumber,suburbId)

Suburb(suburbId(PK),suburbName,cityId)

City(cityId(PK),cityName,stateId)

State(stateId(PK),stateName,countryId)

Country(countryId(PK),countryName)
```

I'm trying to make a query to get the closest landmark which its type=coffee shop to a specific address.
For example:
The closest coffee shop to 54 George Street, Los angles, California, usa .

I'm new to spatial databases, what is the best optimised SQL query to this example.

Comment: You have the coordinates only for landmarks, but not for the addresses. It will be very difficult to write a decent query

Comment: so what do you think,should i move it from landmarks to location table?

Comment: No, I think you should also store some kind of coordinates of suburbs, streets cities, etc